# Cannot get LDAP extension enabled on new PHP IIS server

Tags: php, iis, ldap

I have a new server at work, installed PHP 5.4.21 on it yesterday, got SQLSRV working this morning but now I'm stuck getting LDAP enabled. It's not showing in phpinfo(). This is my php.ini file that is in C:\PHP which is where phpinfo() says is the correct directory: http://pastebin.com/yWv9gRNT

I have uncommented `extension=php_ldap.dll` (near the bottom), I have the dll in the ext folder that is linked in the php.ini file, I have restarted IIS numerous times, I have even copied all DLLs to Windows\System32 folder as recommended on some forums (including libsasl.dll libeay32.dll & ssleay32.dll) & restarted server. Server is Windows 2008 R2 running IIS 7.5.

Comment: LDAP support in PHP is not enabled by default. This is useful http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php

Comment: @Lokesh Thanks, I know it's not enabled, but I have enabled it and followed loads of forum posts and still cannot get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have resolved this, been away for a week, came back to look at it again...
Turns out at the very first time (before posting on here) it wasn't working (the dll files weren't in the system32 folder) I followed a few posts on here where people suggest downloading the latest version of PHP and taking the ext folder and copying over the ones we have installed. Today I downloaded the zip that matches my version exactly, overwrote all the newer dlls and it now works perfectly, thank you to all those that helped and offered their expertise and time.

Answer (score 1):

Add two other dll `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` and compile with `--with-ldap` 
Step by step:
**1** Add extension = php_ldap.dll in php.ini
**2** Make sure that you're editing the right php.ini by checking the output of phpinfo()
**3**Check the php.ini file for the location of your extensions directory
**4**Check that php_ldap.dll is located in that directory
**5** Find the files libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll and add their directory to the Windows PATH
**6** Reboot server. If LDAP is enabled there will be a section about it in the output of phpinfo()

Comment: Really sorry, but what do you mean by "compile with `--with-ldap`"? I've just been searching for what this means since you posted it but I'm not getting anywhere, I already have those dll in ext and in windows/system32

Comment: @Maff You will need to use the --with-ldap[=DIR] configuration option when compiling PHP to enable LDAP support. DIR is the LDAP base install directory. If you would have gone through the link which i have shared it contains all information

Comment: I went to the link when you posted it, but I'm not compiling php (or I'm misunderstanding what that page means), php was a zip file I downloaded and put in c:\php, set it up in IIS, uncommented parts I needed and that's it. I cannot find anything about compiling php

Comment: @Maff You need to compile PHP with LDAP enabled. Or find a windows binary with LDAP enabled.

Comment: @Lokesh it's in the ext folder and windows/system32, php manager says it's enabled but it's not showing in phpinfo()

Comment: @Lokesh in response to your edit, all those already done except number 6 as it's IIS, not apache

Comment: @Maff then reboot IIS and check.

Comment: @Maff try to reinstall the server and try the above steps again